# MVC4 Web API routing conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**ISSUE**

We just switched from MVC4 Web API Beta to the RC and we're running into a `Multiple actions were found that match the request ...` exception in our service.

**BACKGROUND**

We have two `POST` actions defined in our `ApiController`:

```
public class MyModelController : ApiController
{
    ...
    // POST /mymodel
    public MyModel Post(MyModel model)
    {
       ...
    }

    // POST /mymodel/upload
    [ActionName("Upload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadModelImage()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, request));
        }
       ...
    }
}
```

The first action (default `POST` action) is used to create a new `MyModel` object from the JSON passed to the service. The user of our portal has the option to upload an image as part of creating a new `MyModel` object in which case we use the second `Upload` action to save the file and persist the new object to the database. This action reads the multipart request content, parses out the properties for the model and saves the image uploaded to our CDN.

Since our switch to the RC, **the upload action (http://www.myapidomain.com/mymodel/upload) goes through fine, but the regular `POST` action (http://www.myapidomain.com/mymodel/) fails** with the `Multiple actions were found that match the request ...` exception citing both the methods listed above as the conflicts.

Here are our routes:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "Default", // route name
    "{controller}" // route template
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "OnlyId", // route name
    "{controller}/{id}", // route template
    new {}, // defaults
    new {controller = @"[^0-9]+", id = @"[0-9]+"} // constraints
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "OnlyAction", // route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // route template
    new {}, // defaults
    new {controller = @"[^0-9]+", action = ActionNameConstraint.Instance} // constraints
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DependantAction", // route name
    "{controller}/{principalId}/{action}/{dependentId}", // route template
    new {dependentId = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional}, // defaults
    new {controller = @"[^0-9]+", action = ActionNameConstraint.Instance} // constraints
    );
```

`ActionNameConstraint` is just a custom constraint that ensures that the `{action}` must belong to the `{controller}`

**QUESTION**

I've tried messing with the routes in different orders to see if that would fix the issue with no luck. I'm looking for help with any of the following solutions:

1. A potential issue in our routes.
2. An alternative solution for routing by `content-type`. The `Upload` action only needs to be called for mult-part form posts. If the content type is JSON or XML, the regular action should be used. I haven't been able to find any resources that suggest this can be done, but I'm hoping someone else has considered this.
3. A model-binding approach for reading file streams from the request content so we don't need the separate `Upload` action anymore

Comment: If your upload works as you say, there's no need for alternative approach for file streams. Are there other actions in your controller that may be causing conflicts?

Comment: Well the idea with #3 was that an alternative would be to have a view model which has a HttpPostedFile property or something similar that would bind to the input for the file. With this approach we would just need a single `POST` action and therefore remove the conflict.

With regards to your second question: the only conflict seems to be coming from those two actions.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is not possible to mix REST style routing and RPC style routing in a single controller - which it seems you are trying to do.

There is an open issue for that on ASP.NET Web Stack's codeplex, where Web API source lives - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184.

If you want to use it like that, you need to move the upload action to a separate controller, which will be called in an RPC-only way.